# Printing SOAP response in Karate DSL

Tags: soap, karate

I have this feature file and i get a response correctly. I want to print obtained value from response but somehow I am not able to do that. Tried to research some stuff but I couldnt help myself.

Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance

```
Feature: 
    test of soap

Background:
* url 'http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso'

Scenario: soap 1.1
Given request
"""
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:NumberToDollars>
         <web:dNum>10</web:dNum>
      </web:NumberToDollars>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""
When soap action 'Conversion'
Then status 200

* print '\n', response

#working
* match response /Envelope/Body/NumberToDollarsResponse/NumberToDollarsResult == 'ten dollars'

#not working
* print response.Envelope.Body.NumberToDollarsResponse.NumberToDollarsResult

#not working
* print response /Envelope/Body/NumberToDollarsResponse/NumberToDollarsResult

#not working
* def x = response /Envelope/Body/NumberToDollarsResponse/NumberToDollarsResult
* print x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs, `print` only handles JS on the right-hand-side, not XPath.

For what you want, please do in 2 steps:

```
 * def temp = /Envelope/Body/NumberToDollarsResponse/NumberToDollarsResult
 * print temp
```

Comment: Peter, could you clarify for me how to work with this? I am not really sure.
If I do this:

* def temp = /Envelope/Body
* print temp

* def temp2 = temp/NumberToDollarsResponse/NumberToDollarsResult
* print temp2

I am not getting the value (tried more variations)

Comment: @EduardFarkaš XML is tricky. look at the examples and ask a new question if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature